# How to model time series and to find corelation between times of events

Tags: regression, time-series, distributions, anova

I have data set that track daily activity of user. User repeat action one or more times during a day. This actions are independent and I want to determine if there is relation between times of events.

day one
First event: 08.14
Second event: 09:00
Third event: 11.45
Fourth event: 12:00

day two
First event: 08.05
Second event: 09:50
Third event: 11.05

and so on... as you can see number of actions during a day is determine by distribution that is known. Since I know distribution how I can model this times of events.

******************* adding plots of data ********************

[image]

[image]

Comment: So you want to check whether a user repeats these actions at roughly the same time of the day using data from many days? What is this known distribution that you speak of?

Comment: Negative binomial distributon

Comment: Can you post two images of your data, 1) a histogram of all the event times for all the days combined, and 2) a frequency plot of daily events, that is group all the days into one and in each day count the number of events and draw a histogram / barplot.

Comment: @user2974951 I hope that this is what you were asking, this are data for all days. First chart show that there are 72 days with just one action that day.Second chart I choose bin width arround 5 minutes.